How to GET Feature Flag from Gitlab correctly
I have set the following Feature Flag in my gitlab for all users and all environemets as:
feature_flag_test
I have also created a Project Access Token with read_api Scope as:
MY_REPO_READ_API_TOKEN
Now in my gradle I am trying to get the feature flag as in the following code:
def getFeatureFlagStatus(flagName) {
    def apiToken = "MY_REPO_READ_API_TOKEN"
    def projectId = "666" // GitLab project ID
    def flagsUrl = "https://gitlab.mine.local/api/v4/projects/${projectId}/feature_flags"

    try {
        def conn = new URL(flagsUrl).openConnection()
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET")
        conn.setRequestProperty("PRIVATE-TOKEN", apiToken)
        conn.connect()

        def responseString = conn.content.text
        if (responseString.startsWith("<")) { // Check if the response might be HTML
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected HTML response, check URL and authentication")
        }

        def response = new JsonSlurper().parseText(responseString)
        def flag = response.find { it.name == flagName }
        return flag != null ? flag.active : false
    } catch (Exception e) {
        println "Failed to fetch feature flag ($flagName): $e"
        return false
    }
}
def isFeatureActive = getFeatureFlagStatus("feature_flag_test")
println "Is Feature Active: $isFeatureActive"

But I get:
Failed to fetch feature flag (feature_flag_test): java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://gitlab.mine.local/api/v4/projects/666/feature_flags

Is Feature Active old: false

I have verified that the path https://gitlab.mine.local/api/v4/projects/666/feature_flags is correct because I can see the html in my browser.

Am I doing something wrong?
I know that we dont need user authentication to access the api, am I correct?

